# Error: The test runner exited with code -1 before checking in

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

After build finishes without issue, running Xcode 12.4 project's tests fail with message:

```
MyProject.app (10164) encountered an error (
  Early unexpected exit,
  operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (
    Underlying Error: The test runner exited with code -1 before checking in.
    If you believe this error represents a bug,
    please attach the result bundle at /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gczfeuobxydqjrfbdhwzpqjsseyr/Logs/Test/Test-MyApp-2021.09.29_23-12-38-+0430.xcresult
  )
)
```

**What is above message trying to mean?!**
(parenthesis spacing is by me, to make human-readable)

> **About My System:** macOS Catalina <sup>version 10.15.7 (19H2)</sup>
> MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)
> Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
> Memory 4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
> Graphics NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TK;DR;** Either update MacOS to latest, or downgrade Xcode to `11.7` version.

---

At last I found reason, seems **Xcode `11.7`** (or rather it's SDK), is the last version which supports running on **Catalina** version of MacOS
(without any manual extra effort).

But running tests for iOS device works (without macOS update).

Someone please tell Apple to improve their error messages :-(